# CQLSH connection refused on EC2 Cassandra cluster nodes

Tags: amazon-ec2, cassandra, cqlsh, cassandra-cluster

I am trying to set up a Cassandra cluter on four EC2 `t2.2xlarge` nodes, with one node nominated as the seed.  The cluster *seems* to have started on each node.  However, when I try to run /opt/cassandra/bin/cqlsh I get the following error:

```
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': error(111, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")})
```

When I do a netstat on `9042` on the seed node, I get the following output:

```
Proto  Recv-Q  Send-Q  Local Address                Foreign Address             State
tcp         0       0  ip-172-xx-xx-111.eu-wes:9042  *:*                         LISTEN
```

I'm thinking that this host address could be the source of the problem, but don't know how it wouldve got set the that, or how to change it.  Should it be `127.0.0.1` or `localhost`?

I have a security group setup with the following information for port 9042:

```
Type               Protocol    Port Range    Source
-------------------------------------------------------------------------
Custom TCP Rule    TCP         9042          sg-<group-id> (<group-name>)
```

Perhaps the source here is at fault?  Should this be `localhost` or something?

Below are the values in `cassandra.yaml` that I have changed on each node:

```
listen_interface: eth0

broadcast_address: <local-PRIVATE-ip>

rpc_address: <local-PRIVATE-ip>

seed_provider:
# Addresses of hosts that are deemed contact points.
# Cassandra nodes use this list of hosts to find each other and learn
# the topology of the ring.  You must change this if you are running
# multiple nodes!
- class_name: org.apache.cassandra.locator.SimpleSeedProvider
  parameters:
      # seeds is actually a comma-delimited list of addresses.
      # Ex: "<ip1>,<ip2>,<ip3>"
      - seeds: "<seed-node-PRIVATE-ip>"
```

When I start each node the final messages in the logs is:

```
INFO  11:32:44 Node /172.xx.xx.222 state jump to NORMAL
INFO  11:32:44 Waiting for gossip to settle before accepting client requests...
INFO  11:32:44 Compacted 4 sstables to [/var/lib/cassandra/data/system/local-7ad54392bcdd35a684174e047860b377/system-local-ka-13,].  11,190 bytes to 5,773 (~51% of original) in 24ms = 0.229398MB/s.  4 total partitions merged to 1.  Partition merge counts were {4:1, }
INFO  11:32:52 No gossip backlog; proceeding
```

The final few lines of the seed nodes logs are:

```
INFO  11:58:35 Enqueuing flush of local: 578 (0%) on-heap, 0 (0%) off-heap
INFO  11:58:35 Writing Memtable-local@1006553205(0.081KiB serialized bytes, 4 ops, 0%/0% of on/off-heap limit)
INFO  11:58:35 Completed flushing /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/local-7ad54392bcdd35a684174e047860b377/system-local-tmp-ka-14-Data.db (0.000KiB) for commitlog position ReplayPosition(segmentId=1550836714360, position=94125)
INFO  11:58:35 Handshaking version with /172.xx.xx.222
INFO  11:58:35 Node /172.xx.xx.333 has restarted, now UP
INFO  11:58:35 Handshaking version with /172.xx.xx.333
INFO  11:58:35 Node /172.xx.xx.333 state jump to NORMAL
INFO  11:58:35 Enqueuing flush of local: 51462 (0%) on-heap, 0 (0%) off-heap
INFO  11:58:35 Writing Memtable-local@961534831(8.349KiB serialized bytes, 259 ops, 0%/0% of on/off-heap limit)
INFO  11:58:35 Completed flushing /var/lib/cassandra/data/system/local-7ad54392bcdd35a684174e047860b377/system-local-tmp-ka-15-Data.db (0.000KiB) for commitlog position ReplayPosition(segmentId=1550836714360, position=106779)
INFO  11:58:35 InetAddress /172.xx.xx.333 is now UP
INFO  11:58:35 Node /172.xx.xx.111 state jump to NORMAL
INFO  11:58:35 Updating topology for /172.xx.xx.333
INFO  11:58:35 Updating topology for /172.xx.xx.333
INFO  11:58:35 Node /172.xx.xx.444 has restarted, now UP
INFO  11:58:35 Waiting for gossip to settle before accepting client requests...
INFO  11:58:35 Node /172.xx.xx.444 state jump to NORMAL
INFO  11:58:35 Handshaking version with /172.xx.xx.444
INFO  11:58:35 InetAddress /172.xx.xx.444 is now UP
INFO  11:58:35 Updating topology for /172.xx.xx.444
INFO  11:58:35 Updating topology for /172.xx.xx.444
INFO  11:58:35 Node /172.xx.xx.222 has restarted, now UP
INFO  11:58:35 Node /172.xx.xx.222 state jump to NORMAL
INFO  11:58:35 InetAddress /172.xx.xx.222 is now UP
INFO  11:58:35 Updating topology for /172.xx.xx.222
INFO  11:58:35 Updating topology for /172.xx.xx.222
INFO  11:58:38 Updating topology for all endpoints that have changed
INFO  11:58:43 No gossip backlog; proceeding
```

So each of the IPs of the other non-seed nodes (`172.xx.xx.222/333/444`) seems to be reported as `UP`.  The seed node (`172.xx.xx.111`) just reports as `state jump to NORMAL`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
Connection error: ('Unable to connect to any servers', {'127.0.0.1': error(111, "Tried connecting to [('127.0.0.1', 9042)]. Last error: Connection refused")})
```

It looks like you're trying to connect via CQLSH to 127.0.0.1, which does not work in a plural node cluster.  Specify the exact (broadcast) IP, with your credentials, and it should let you in.

Ex:

```
$ grep _address conf/cassandra.yaml | grep -v "#"

listen_address: 192.168.1.4
broadcast_address: 10.1.3.6
rpc_address: 192.168.1.4
broadcast_rpc_address: 10.1.3.6

$ bin/cqlsh 10.1.3.6 -u flynn -p reindeerFlotilla

Connected to AaronTest at 10.1.3.6:9042.
[cqlsh 5.0.1 | Cassandra 3.11.2 | CQL spec 3.4.4 | Native protocol v4]
Use HELP for help.
flynn@cqlsh>
```